# Como exibo o nome de um usuario através do ID do usuario com LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um blog em laravel para praticar o que ja aprendi até agora no curso que estou fazendo, a principio ja fiz as minhas tabelas no banco de dados e o relacionamento entre elas, a principio são duas tabelas, a de usuario e a de postagens, no meu PostController estou trazendo todas as postagens dessa forma:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Estou passando a variável $posts para a view dessa forma:

```
return view('home', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

e está funcionando corretamente, consigo passar o titulo para a postagem, subtítulo o artigo, tudo funciona muito bem, o problema está ocorrendo quando eu tento exibir o nome do autor, quando eu criei minha table de posts eu relacionei o id do autor com a postagem, então quando eu dou um dd($posts) ele aparece os dados da postagem e o ID do usuário que postou, minha duvida é como eu faço para extrair o nome referente a esse ID.

Print do dd($posts):

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8suH.png)

Eu quero resgatar o nome do id_user = 14, desculpem se expliquei mal ou me estendi demais.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode utilizar o método de relacionamento "with" do Eloquent para carregar os dados do usuário junto com as postagens. Primeiro, você precisa definir o relacionamento na sua model de postagem:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Então, você pode carregar o usuário junto com as postagens utilizando o método "with":

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Dessa forma, você pode acessar os dados do usuário através do objeto de postagem, como por exemplo $post->user->name.

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->user->name;
}
```

Mais informações sobre relacionamento no eloquent segue o doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Espero ter ajudado!